# How to remote access IP cam through VPN by iPhone

Tags: openvpn, iphone, nat, pfsense, ip-camera

**iPhone <--[pfSense]OpenVPN--> IP Cam**

Remote network: 15.0.0.15 (iPhone)

pfSense OpenVPN server: 10.0.8.0

Local network: 192.168.1.0

IP Cam: 192.168.1.99

**What i want:**

a) Block all outgoing traffic from IP Cam (by LAN block rule & it works)

b) iPhone can access to the IP Cam web interface (by LAN pass rule & it works)

c) IP Cam app can search local LAN & found the IP Cam (didn't work)

**Questions:**

1) Is it possible for c) to work?

maybe map a vIP to local IP (iPhone pretended in LAN)? or the other way round?

2) if it's possible, how? (tried with NAT 1:1 setting, didn't work)

**Not perfect solution now:**

iPhone change to a ONVIF IP Cam app, which could playback live stream from IP Cam, but can not control the motion.